# storing $.each() value in variable and using it

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, each, sub-array

I have a sub array, and I am trying to store the results of the sub array like this inside a variable.

```
$.each(abc[0].Phone, function (i, item) {
   var number = '<p> '+ item.Phone +'</p>';
 });
```

Then I am trying to use this variable inside another variable

```
var temp = '<div class="row">\n\
              <div class="col-md-6">\n\
                <h4>' + abc[0].FullName + '</h4>\n\
                  <p>Phone: '+ number +' </p>\n\
               </div>\n\
             </div>';
```

I get the error that number is not declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope Problem and bind outside the loop .

```
   var number = '';
    $.each(abc[0].Phone, function (i, item) {
        number += '<p> '+ item.Phone +'</p>'; // For repeated  phone
     });
```

And use of number.

```
var temp = '<div class="row">\n\
              <div class="col-md-6">\n\
                <h4>' + abc[0].FullName + '</h4>\n\
                  <p>Phone: '+ number +' </p>\n\
               </div>\n\
             </div>';
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because, the variable number is available only inside the function and not outside it! Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) for more on scope of variables in javascript!

So you need to assign temp and perform the related functionalities inside each function.

```
var number=''
$.each(abc[0].Phone, function (i, item) {

   number =number+ '<p> '+ item.Phone +'</p>';
 }); 

   var temp = '<div class="row">\n\
              <div class="col-md-6">\n\
                <h4>' + abc[0].FullName + '</h4>\n\
                  <p>Phone: '+ number +' </p>\n\
               </div>\n\
             </div>';
$('#dynamic-content').html(temp);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The only problem with this is that I have more than one sub array that I wanna use in temp, then will hand temp to `$('#dynamic-content').html(temp);` your solution will cause temp to be not declared in the `html(templ)`

Comment: the sub array have more than one number .. So, It made the the content show up twice .. if i had more than two numbers it will repeate more

Comment: That wansnt clear in the question! I've adde the edit!